# macro does not find out enclosing vals

Tags: scala, macros

I tried collecting all vals in an enclosing scope.

This is the macro implementation:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macro.blackbox.Context

def impl(c: Context) = {
  import c.universe._
  c.Expr[Seq[Any]](q"Seq(..${
    c.internal.enclosingOwner.owner.typeSignature.decls.collect {
      case s if s.isTerm && s.asTerm.isVal => Ident(s)
    }
  })")
}

def get(c: Context) = macro impl
```

This is how I applied it:

```
object Foo {
  val foo = ""
  def poo = get
}
```

Then it threw an error that doesn't make sense to me:

```
error: symbol value foo does not exist in Foo.poo
```

Why does this happen? How do you prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the `Ident` method that takes a symbol, you want `Ident.apply`, which takes a `Name`.

Replacing `Ident(s)` with `Ident(s.name)` (or maybe a little more clearly `q"this.$s"`) will work.

Comment: Oh it worked :) Thank you! Do you think `Ident(Name)` can be used anytime? Are there any cases that I should use `Ident(Symbol)`?

Comment: To be honest I haven't used `Ident` and friends much since quasiquotes were introduced, and off the top of my head I can't think of cases where I used `Ident(symbol)` before, or examples in the documentation, etc.

Comment: @RyoichiroOka: If you're really curious you could ping Eugene Burmako on Twitter or IRC (haven't seen him around here much lately).